# Can a Scala function be written such that it gets any function and returns it with its arguments reversed?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I know this is trivial in a lisp, but Scala has a strong type system which makes me doubt if such a function is possible. 
If it is not possible, what about macros? Can a Scala macro do this?

PS: Here is the function in Clojure:

```
 (fn [f](fn f* [& args] (apply f (reverse args))))
```

Comment: Are the arguments all of the same type? When would I need it? If the arguments are of different type, I would call the reversing function with arguments, which don't match in the order I pass them? If I don't execute the function immediatly, why would I pass the function and not just the arguments to reverse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difficulty is that you have to find out the type of the function with reversed arguments, and it's not possible to do that without macros in a generic way.

But because Scala supports only functions of up to 22 arguments, you can just write or generate 23 implementations for functions of all possible arities. Here is an example for a function of 3 arguments:

```
def reverse[A, B, C, R](f: (A, B, C) => R): (C, B, A) => R = 
  (c, b, a) => f(a, b, c)
```

With macros though it's possible to do it in a generic way. The simplest solution is probably to use the [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library, which is implemented using macros internally. Here is a sample implemetation with shapeless:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.function._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

def reverseArgs[Func, Args <: HList, Res, RevArgs <: HList](f: Func)(implicit
  // Convert the function to a function from a single HList argument.
  fnToProduct: FnToProduct.Aux[Func, Args => Res], 
  // Compute the type of the reversed arguments HList.
  r1: Reverse.Aux[Args, RevArgs],
  // Get the function to reverse the reversed arguments back.
  reverse: Reverse.Aux[RevArgs, Args],
  // Convert the function of a single HList argument to a normal function
  fnFromProduct: FnFromProduct[RevArgs => Res]
): fnFromProduct.Out = {
  fnFromProduct((args: RevArgs) => fnToProduct(f)(reverse(args)))
}
```

Here is how it works:

```
scala> val f = reverseArgs((i: Int, d: Double, s: String) => (i + d).toString + s)
f: (String, Double, Int) => String = shapeless.ops.FnFromProductInstances$$anon$4$$Lambda$1191/2014583896@4d7933e7

scala> f("a", 1.5, 2)
res1: String = 3.5a
```

Comment: Can you also add the case of a function with arity 3 using pure Scala (no macros)? And I don't understand why you defined r1. You didn't use it. (I don't know any Shapeless so perhaps that's why).

Comment: @HappyFace I've added one case with pure Scala. As for `r1`, yes, I didn't use it. As the comment says it's there simply to compute the type of the reversed argument list. The real function used is the reverse of reverse (the one called `reverse`).